# Kung foo invocations strike multiple times, how to know what called the method from a test?

Tags: c#, nunit, moq

OK - so I have this test. I wrote it expecting it would fail because my OnSaveCommand does call my adapters Save method yet. But to my surprise it failed saying "Invocation was performed more than once on the mock". I am totally confused. I am not called it at all *goink*. My problem is I don't know how to tell what is called it? If I where running the code I would throw in a break point and just look at the call stack when it gets called but that doesn't really work here because it's a mock of course.

I tried to look at the moq quickstart for some ideas but the truth is I am just stumped. The first part of the test publishes an event that causes the DiscountsForSelectedCompany list to get populated, I can see that all that happens, then I execute the save command right? Then I get the error. Like I said, I am stumped - if someone could point me in the right direction that would be awesome.

```
[Test]
public void SaveCommand_Will_Call_Adapter_SaveDiscounts_For_All_Edited_Discounts()
{
    eventAggregator.GetEvent<SetCompanyIdEvent>().Publish(182);

    vm.DiscountsForSelectedCompany.Single(x => x.Id == 1).IsEdited = true;
    mockVariablePricingAdapter.Setup(x => x.SaveDiscounts(
            It.Is<List<DisplayCompanyDiscount>>(a => a.First().Id == 1))
        ).Verifiable();

    vm.SaveCommand.Execute();
    mockVariablePricingAdapter.Verify(x => x.SaveDiscounts(It.Is<List<DisplayCompanyDiscount>>(a => a.First().Id == 1)), Times.Once());
}
```

Thanks!

EIDT! WHOO - HEY!!! I changed the "Times.Once()" to "Times.AtLeastOnec()" and sure enough if fails saying "Invocation was not performed on the mock:" - Does anyone know about this? Is it a bug?

Comment: you had me at `Kung foo <something> strike multiple times` ;)

Comment: Does [Using MOQ to test non-primitive arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245710/using-moq-to-test-methods-that-accept-non-primative-arguments) solve your issue?

Comment: I changed it to Times.Exactly(1) which solves the issue and tests the behavior exactly as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

A few points and comments.

First off the third line of your test is unnecessary since your are explicitly identifying your verify on your last line.  If you want to leave the .setup(…).verifiable() in then the last line should just be .Verify();

As far as finding the reason for two calls, first off I would set a brake point at an appropriate place in your code and step through to find the two calls.  If that isn’t helpful replace the Moq with a manual mock and put a breakpoint in the SaveDiscounts of the manual mock.

Happy coding and I hope this is helpful.